# Windows DHCP IOT retain same IP

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, dhcpv6, dhcp-option

I am trying to address a problem.
We have a windows DHCP server and some devices, which we need to replace on needs. The device has a custom DHCP client which sends DHCP-DISCOVERY Packet with additional vendor-specific unique information,(It is tested, and works). When a device is replaced it will have the same unique details as the previous device. MAC address is different.

here is the problem, When a new device is installed since the mac address is changed, windows DHCP is assigning different IP.

DHCP reservation works based on mac address and DHCP reservation is not what I am looking for. Are there any other options?

Option 1.
Install Custom DHCP Server which will respond only to Packent sent from these devices. This dhcp server will assign IP from a db lookup based on vendor property in the DHCP packet. The windows server will respond to all requests and this device will only acknowledge responses from the custom DHCP server. Since the IP ranges are split. Hope this solution will not impact the network.

Expecting comments and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. DHCP Option 61 is the right solution for this. Instead of custom client and server, windows dhcp server can reserve IP based on option 61